# Bundled .app file is not running in /Application folder

Tags: macos, package, jarbundler

I have bundled my.jar to Mac OSX .app file using [jarbundler2.4](https://github.com/tofi86/Jarbundler) and  using [universalJavaStubApplication](https://github.com/tofi86/universalJavaApplicationStub)
The generated .app is running on my Desktop folder but not running in /Application directory. I already tried changing the permission of file, yet its of no help.

Any idea how to solve this would be helpful.

Thanks,
Pawan

Comment: Does it run in any other folder? I gues that there are some hardcoded link. Can you launch the app from terminal. Like "./AppName.app/Contents/MacOS/AppName" ? If yes does it report any message? What's the generated bundle structure. Post more details.

Comment: I am able to launch the app from terminal only on Desktop folder, not in /Application as stated by you. The output are exactly same in both case. I guess there is something wrong with 

    exec "$JAVACMD" \
        -cp "${JVMClassPath}" \
        -Xdock:icon="${ResourcesFolder}/${CFBundleIconFile}" \
        -Xdock:name="${CFBundleName}" \
        ${JVMOptions:+$JVMOptions }\
        ${JVMDefaultOptions:+$JVMDefaultOptions }\
        ${JVMMainClass}\
        ${JVMArguments:+ $JVMArguments}
However parameter in both cases are same

Comment: As I said, you have absolute link. One of those variables is absolute instead of relative. Also launch console.app to see error messages when you launch the app from Application folder